# Installed 'matplotlib' using Anaconda. Not finding 'pyplot' in Pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, anaconda

I have installed '**matplotlib**' using Anaconda (today).
I am using '**PyCharm**' from the Anaconda interface itself.

When I try to import a package from '**matplotlib**', I see other namespaces getting listed. But I do not see '**pyplot**'.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to get around this by pasting the files in the file system after downloading it from the Github.